# Flutter: Changing AppBar title dynamically when navigating from specific card on previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter and trying to dynamically change the appBar title of the input screen based on the card exercise name that is tapped on the previous screen.

For example if the user taps on the Barbell Row card (see link to images below) - the input screen appBar title will become Barbell Row.

What is the best way to achieve this?

[Previous Card screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8IWE.png)

[Single Card Input Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx9B6.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good way to pass data

```
class PreviousScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              navigate(context, "Hello");
            },
            child: Text("Hello"),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              navigate(context, "Bar Bell");
            },
            child: Text("Bar bell"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigate(BuildContext context, String text){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignleCardInputScreen(text: text,)));
  }

}

class SignleCardInputScreen extends StatelessWidget {

final String text;

  const SignleCardInputScreen({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's good practice to create a navigate method that accepts the String since you'll be doing it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. It works perfectly well.

**FIRST SCREEN**

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'First Screen'
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondScreen('Babel Row'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Babel Row')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondScreen('Bench Press'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Bench Press')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SECOND SCREEN**

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // define a string variable
  final String name;

  // create a constructor
  const SecondScreen(this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // set the app bar title here
        title: Text(name),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I hope this helps.